# Dynamic object array

Tags: javascript

In javascript we have array with static number of objects.

```
objectArray = [{}, {}, {}];
```

Can someone please explain to me how can I make this number dynamical?

Comment: add a dynamic amount of indexes.  I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: Why don't you read some documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object

Comment: I read, but another, thank you for this one)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to make it dynamic, it already is.  You merely need to add more objects onto the array:

```
// Add some new objects
objectArray.push({});
objectArray.push({});
console.log(objectArray.length); // 5

// Remove the last one
objectArray.pop();
console.log(objectArray.length); // 4
```

In JavaScript, array lengths need not be declared. They're always dynamic.

You can modify the individual objects by array key:

```
// Add a property to the second object:
objectArray[1].newProperty = "a new property value!";
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify an array size when first creating the array if you don't want to. You can use:

```
var objectArray=new Array();
```

to create the array and add elements by:

```
objectArray[0] = "something";
objectArray[1] = "another thing";
objectArray[2] = "and so on";
```